# Проверить наличие клоакинга

Tags: битрикс, seo

От SEO ребят прилетела задача, проверить на клоакинг ресурс, и найти проблему и решить ее если она есть, суть проблемы изучил но это не помогает решить проблему, анализ сайта выдает разный размер данных для useragentОв(скрин прикладываю):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

также прогнал через сравнение разницы когда, выдает следующие разные строки:

```
<script>new Image().src='https://xxxxxx.dev-ravidok.ru/bitrix/spread.php?s=QklUUklYX1NNX1NBTEVfVUlEATBlMjQxYzc5MWFjZTNhMWI0MGNmN2JjODE1MjI1ODhhATE2ODM1MjkwMTEBLwEBAQI%3D&k=38bf2da1104521d51b0f678441714145';

    new Image().src='https://xxxxxx.ru/bitrix/spread.php?s=QklUUklYX1NNX1NBTEVfVUlEATBlMjQxYzc5MWFjZTNhMWI0MGNmN2JjODE1MjI1ODhhATE2ODM1MjkwMTEBLwEBAQI%3D&k=38bf2da1104521d51b0f678441714145';
```

и

```
<script>new Image().src='https://xxxxxx.dev-ravidok.ru/bitrix/spread.php?s=QklUUklYX1NNX0dVRVNUX0lEATM3OTI1MQExNjgzNTI4OTk3AS8BAQECQklUUklYX1NNX0xBU1RfVklTSVQBMTMuMDUuMjAyMiAwOTo1NjozNwExNjgzNTI4OTk3AS8BAQECQklUUklYX1NNX1NBTEVfVUlEATRmMzM5OWIxZDY2MzdjMmFkZGE3YjNiY2ZjMWJhZjNmATE2ODM1Mjg5OTcBLwEBAQI%3D&k=118a97cc7ae88c0ae3f8e7b397510235';

new Image().src='https://xxxxxx.ru/bitrix/spread.php?s=QklUUklYX1NNX0dVRVNUX0lEATM3OTI1MQExNjgzNTI4OTk3AS8BAQECQklUUklYX1NNX0xBU1RfVklTSVQBMTMuMDUuMjAyMiAwOTo1NjozNwExNjgzNTI4OTk3AS8BAQECQklUUklYX1NNX1NBTEVfVUlEATRmMzM5OWIxZDY2MzdjMmFkZGE3YjNiY2ZjMWJhZjNmATE2ODM1Mjg5OTcBLwEBAQI%3D&k=118a97cc7ae88c0ae3f8e7b397510235';
```

вот эти они отличаются по версии Labrika.ru, но как это исправить и нужно ли?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Клоакинг это когда боту одно, пользователю другое, вы же пытаетесь все ботом проверить

Comment: Та же самая проблема в лабрике с сайтом на битриксе. Подскажите вам получилось эту проблему решить? если да, пожалуйста, напишите решение